# how to display main form for tablet or mobile phone in MSCRM 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm

i am working on MSCRM 2016. The problem is "how to display main form for tablet or mobile phone?" every time it's loading quick create form.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a browser or the Dynamics CRM app on mobile/table?

You can try disabling quick create in the entity customization or try inactivating the quick create form and see what shows up on mobile/table.

Comment: Disable form or inactivate is not possible. getting error "You can’t deactivate this type of form."
I am using MOCA app for access CRM application

Comment: Can you try going to the solution > your entity, and uncheck Allow quick create?